# How do I get the current working directory with the least amount of dependencies possible?

Tags: rust, directory, working-directory

I have a Rust application which works as a shell. I want to get the working directory the user is in using as little dependencies as possible.

I tried using

```rust
let path = env::current_dir();
print!("{} > ",path.display());
```

But it gives me the following error: `` method not found in `Result<PathBuf, std::io::Error>' ``

I tried running this in the rust playground and it worked alright, so I was wondering if any of you could help me with this

Comment: Do you want the executable's path or the user's current working directory?

Comment: Notably "the path the executable is in" and "the current folder the user is in" aren't always the same.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify which of the two you want.

Comment: As for the error about `Result`, see the paragraph I added to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71270401/5445670).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::env::current_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html) to get the current working directory.

You also need to use [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html), [`std::result::Result::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap), [`std::result::Result::expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect), [`?`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-question-mark-operator), or [something else](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) to handle the [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err) variant of the [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) and access the value inside the [`Ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Ok) variant.